# Как в C# рефлексивно инициализировать объекта в массиве

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Есть класс:

```
class cls
{
    public int val1;
    public float val2;
    public cls val3;
    public cls[] val4;
}
```

Цель: сделать метод, который с помощью рекурсии и рефлексии заполнит класс данными. Рефлексия обязательна, как мне инициализировать объект в массиве?

Мой код:

```
public void DOReflection(object cls, Reader Read)
    {
        foreach (var prop in cls.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.IsArray)
            {
                var length = Read.ReadLength();
                object value = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType, length);

                foreach (var item in (object[])value)
                {
                    item = //нужно создать экземляр объекта в массиве
                    DOReflection(item,Read)
                }

                prop.SetValue(cls, value);
            }
            else
            {
                object value = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
                prop.SetValue(cls, value);
                DoReflection(value, Read);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю воспользоваться классом Array

```
Array array = (Array)value;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    array.SetValue(//задаваемое значение
        , i);
}
```